# jQuery Interrupt ASP.net server placed <submit />

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I've got some really odd behavior I basically want a pretty styling to my buttons and I want a modal confirmation form on saving and discarding changes to a web form. The events that do the saving and discarding are asp.net events tied to server controls, by decorating the buttons with a class I can get jQuery to make them look pretty and clicking on them works as if they were bog standard server side controls.

So I wrote a little script that basically goes:

```
$("#confirmSave-dialog").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 150,
    modal: true,
    buttons: { 'Save': function() {
        $(".SAVER").trigger('click');
        $(this).dialog('close');
    },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

$(".SAVER").button();

$(".SAVER").click(function(event) {

    var bool = $("#confirmSave-dialog").dialog('isOpen');
    if (!bool) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#confirmSave-dialog").dialog('open');
    }
});
```

The idea being that when the user clicks the button it brings up a control and interrupts the click event causing a postback but if they click save on the form then the click event sees the form is open and should not interrupt the postback. The issue is that it seems random if this works. It wasn't working and I moved it to a separate function and whacked in some debugger directives like so:

```
    $(".SAVER").click(function(event) {

    var bool = $("#confirmSave-dialog").dialog('isOpen');
    if (!bool) {
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#confirmSave-dialog").dialog('open');
    }
    debugger;
});
```

With Firebug running every now and then it fires the event as it should, with Firebug not running it never does, without the debugger directives it never does.

Even with the debugger running it follows the right path the first time the event is triggered by the click it goes and kicks up the dialog and then when save is clicked it skips out the `event.preventDefault();` call but doesn't fire the postback.

No idea why; any ideas/ways to fix/ better ways of firing the serverside event?

Comment: maybe try catching the .submit event instead of .click???

Comment: same issue unfortunately ? or do you mean catch and interupt click and then fire submit ? (which i tried and couldn't get to work) thanks tho

Answer (score 0):

Try controlling the postback manually in your JS function. So clicking the button always interupts the postback. Works for me everytime.

So on the button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnMyButton" runat="server" class="button" Text="Save Form" OnClientClick="return mySubmit();return false;"  />
```

Then create a mySubmit JS Function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function mySubmit() {

            if (!Foo == Bar ) {


                //return false to cancel the page postback or form submit
                return false;

            } else {

                // manually call the postback (Asp.net only)
                 __doPostBack('<%= btnMyButton.UniqueID%>', '')
                // return true to submit the page. 
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: using that can i hook up the button to an onClick event in the code behind .. and use the return true from my function to fire that event ? or will placing this event here override that or vice versa ? i would prefer if it was possible to do this to dynamically placed controls but if not it's not the end of the world. in your ASP code you say OnClientClick="return mySubmit();return false;", tried this and the compiler has a go. probably because that's meant to be psuedo code ?? havent done much of the markup side mostly done code behind content generation so don't get how to set this up,thanks